# When people say KOA2, what exactly are they saying?

Tags: node.js, npm, koa, koa2

Does anybody know what the relationship is between KOA and KoA2 in NPM?

Recently I was trying to use the KOA framework, and I was wondering which of the two code repositories in NPM, KOA and KoA2, What should I use? Or, when people say Koa2, they mean KOA 2.x and not Koa2 in npm?

If I want to use koa2 , what code repositories should I use ? koa or koa2 ?

Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Use the `koa` package, which is on version 2.x.

Comment: If you're talking about this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa2, then I think it's the same as the official koa package https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa. Since they both have the same GitHub homepage. It seems to me the koa2 npm package is just a copy of the official one as it only has a single contributor.

Comment: Comparing the version records of Koa and KoA2 on https://www.npmjs.com/, I found the version contained in KoA2 in Koa at the same time node. I agree with Kartik Chauhan @Kartik Chauhan. Thank you very much for your answers! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I just installed both of these side-by-side and diffed the installed code.

The NPM package `koa2` at npmjs.com/package/koa2 is a *clone*, not a fork of the NPM package `koa@2.0.0-alpha.7` at npmjs.com/package/koa — with some minor changes.

Stuff like this can pose security issues. The problem is that Evildoers™ publish NPM packages with names similar to a popular package. That package contains a trojan of some sort. People install it either by making a typo and not realizing it or by being confused about which is the real deal. So there's that.

In this case, I do not believe `koa2` is malignant, but I would stay away from it.

Especially since Koa itself is currently (9 October 2020) at version 2.13.0.